# Consume a swift defined convenience init in an objective c method

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have a swift extension to NSAttributedString defined in a swift package as below:

```
@objc public extension NSAttributedString {
    convenience init?(html: String) {
        //Do custom clean up
    }
}
```

I have successfully imported the package and imported the module into my Objective-C class:

```
@import MySwiftPackage;
```

However, when I go to create a new `NSAttributedString`, the I get an `No visible @interface for 'NSAttributedString' declares the selector 'html'` error:

```
NSAttributedString *test = [[NSAttributedString alloc] html]
```

Where am I going wrong on this one?

Comment: And where did you put the parameter? It should be `[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHtml: @"yourHTMLString"];` And there is no autcompletion?

Comment: @Larme I'm mostly a Swift guy, so I'm expecting just html. Is initWithHtml some form of auto-renaming that happens when you import swift into Objective c?

Comment: No, you where expecting in Swift: `NSAttributedString.init(html: "yourHTMLString")`, you weren't passing the `html` parameter. Then, you might not have imported the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C compiler expects your initializer to be called as `initWithHtml:` (as @Larme suggested in comments).

This should work:

```
NSString *myHtmlString = @"String you want to pass as 'html' parameter to your init";
NSAttributedString *test = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHtml:myHtmlString];
```

Your extension looks good, because it's marked as `@objc` and `public`, so it doesn't need any changes.